# In our AngularJS application API call getting the information from disk catch inserted of making new API call every time

Tags: angularjs, api

In our angular application, we are implementing a timmer function and calling the one API until a particular value (balance amount) changes in API call with 10 seconds interval with the limit of 5 times.

After we implement the timer function. We absolved that instead of making API call every time. API call taking the value from the disk catch some times.

Can anyone suggest me what is the solution to make API call not take get the information form desk catch?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdy6v.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you can do. At server-side from API, pass `no-cache` header from HTTP response

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

OR you can also add timestamp to your API call URL. So that browser doesn't cache it. Something like this :

```
var url = "http://api.mydomain.com/some-end-point?v=" + (new Date()).getTime();
```